# Groovy traverse only shows one file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I have the following script running on my Jenkins master

```
def workspace = pwd()
def sourceDir = new File(workspace)

println "Files: Traverse"
sourceDir.traverse(type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/.*\.cpp/) {
    println it.path
}
```

This only returns a single file nothing more:

```
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] echo
Files: Traverse
[Pipeline] echo
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job/project/Source/A/a.cpp
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I have confirmed that workspace contains all the files required, I am using Jenkins v1.651.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely related to this bug:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481

Workaround is to use a @NonCPS helper method, e.g. something like:

```
@NonCPS
def traverseHelper() {
    new File(pwd()).traverse(type: FileType.FILES, nameFilter: ~/.*\.cpp/) {
        println it.path
    }
}

println "Files: Traverse"
traverseHelper()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this through the script console and it worked fine for the directory I specified.

Are you sure that you are starting the traverse from the correct directory? What is the value of `workspace`? Maybe it's starting further down the directory tree than you intended.

Comment: workspace outputs as /var/lib/jenkins/job/ which is correct.